# Call array of functions after Timeout - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timeout

So, I have an array of function, e.g.:

```
var functions = [
                 function(){alert('foo');},
                 function(){alert('bar');}
                ];
```

Is it possible to call all the functions in this array after a Timeout, like this:?

```
setTimeout(/*insert function 1 and 2 here*/, 2000);
```

Comment: no. you can only pass ONE callback to settimeout. But you can have that callback call your OTHER functions for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    for (var n = functions.length, i = 0; i < n; i++) functions[i]();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: @Ood You could choose this answer as "accepted" if it solve your problem